# How can I ignore an email attachment if missing from folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 things I need amending

I currently have code that pulls from column A the email address and attaches 3 files which are identified in columns B C and D. However the files in column D are not always present, and I would like the code to ignore them if not found.

Also, can the email include the users standard signature?

```
Sub email1()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change worksheet


If fileExists("g:\test\", Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xls") Then
For i = 2 To lastRow

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

With OutLookMailItem
.SentOnBehalfOfName = " test@test.co.uk "
    .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
    '.cc = "test@test.co.uk"
    .Subject = Cells(i, 6).Value
    .Body = Cells(i, 7).Value
 Attach.Add " g:\test\", \" & Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xls"
            .Display 'for debugging
    SendKeys "^{ENTER}"
  End If
End With
SendKeys "^{ENTER}"
Next
MsgBox ("Emails have all been Sent Successfully")
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing if the `.From` address can be assigned? Verifying whether `Dir("f:\test\" & Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xls")` returns an empty string or not before attempting to attach it?

Comment: Maybe a few suggestions - 1. There are questions on SO that will answer how to send from a shared mailbox, and how to populate the email with your signature. 2. Move `Set OutlookApp = ...` _outside_  your loop, since you only need to do it once.

Comment: the From has been rectified, i am struggling with the 2 other points

Comment: thanks for all the assistance im now trying to create another module that only produces emails when particular files exist.   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping it in a condition if 'fileExists' or something like this...

```
If fileExists("f:\test", Cells(i, 4).Value & ".xls") Then 
     Attach.Add "f:\test\" & Cells(i, 4).Value & ".xls"
End If
```

Then create function to test for the files existence.

```
Function fileExists(s_directory As String, s_fileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim obj_fso As Object
    Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fileExists = obj_fso.fileExists(s_directory & "\" & s_fileName)
End Function
```